# If i delete Account record Contact should be deleted automatically....Is below code correct actually i'm getting error

Tags: account

```
trigger r4 on Account(before delete){
  for(Account c:Trigger.Old){
   Contact cc=new Contact();
   if(cc.isDelete=='True'){
     List<Contact> c3=[Select Id,LastName from Contact where Id IN:cc.AccountId];
   }
  }
  delete c3;
  }
```

Comment: Can you send me the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily

```
trigger accountTrigger on Account(before delete){

     List<Contact> c3=[Select Id,LastName from Contact where AccountId IN: Trigger.old];
     delete c3;
  }
```

If you want to do for `undelete` then that case you need to handle manually.